# Find a word within a paragraph, and wrap it in a span

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery snippet to wrap a span around a specified piece of text:

```
$("h2:contains('cow')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(/(cow)/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>')
});
```

In this instance, the word 'cow' is the target. However, I only want the word 'cow' to be highlighted, not words that contain 'cow' such as 'cows' or 'cowbodys'.

How can I do this?

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w5ze6/454/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to

```
$("h2:contains('cow')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(/\b(cow)\b/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>')
});
```

`\b` in a regular expression is a word boundary. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters).

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: `\b` as it allows you to perform a "`whole word only`" search using a regular expression

```js
$("h2:contains('cow')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(/\b(cow)\b/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>')
});
```

```css
span { color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>We have cows on cowboy town cow</h2>
```